# Template operator specialization from another class

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to change the behavior of an `operator+` method for the case where I need less of it implemented within the method of another class.
If someone here could give me a hand with one or more of the following I'd be much obliged:

1. Maybe I've been searching wrong? If so, a link to the correct answer or source of info would be great.
2. General way to code something like this?

Some code example with the scenario:

```c++
class Rational
{
public:
    const Rational Rational::operator+(const Rational &other) const {
        Rational ans;
        ans._denominator = other.getDenominator() * getDenominator();
        ans._numerator = getNumerator() * other.getDenominator() +
            other.getNumerator() * getDenominator();
        ans.init_rational(); /* <-- This part formats the rational number
                                    every time so that it'd look like 1/2
                                    instead of 2/4(f.e). The purpose of the
                                    specialized method in the other class is
                                    to perform the trace() method where lots
                                    of x+x+x is performed, therefore it'd be
                                    slow and unnecessary to use
                                    "init_rational()" before it's done adding
                             */
        return ans;
    }
};
```

The class where the specialized operator+ is needed:

```c++
template <class T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    int rows, cols;
    vector<vector<T>> mat;
public:
    const bool trace(T& ans) const
    {
        if (_rows() != _cols())
        {
            ans = T();
            return false;
        }
        ans = T();
        for (int i = 0; i < _rows(); i++)
        {
            ans = ans + mat[i][i];
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

BTW, I suppose what I'm trying to accomplish can be done without the specialization that I asked for with a specialization for the whole `Rational` type instead, is that the actual answer here? Or is what I'm looking for an option too?

P.S: If you feel like more info/methods are needed, just ask :p

EDIT:
From the responses I'm getting here I guess I'm not meant to do it the way I wanted, what about doing something like this though?

```c++
template <Rational>
    const bool trace(Rational& ans) const{
        if (_rows() != _cols()){
            ans = Rational();
            return false;
        }
        ans = Rational();
        for (int i = 0; i < _rows(); i++){
            //adding method implemented here or in a separate function in the Rational class
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: "I need less of it implemented within the method of another class." I don't understand what this means.

Comment: Don't return by const value from functions unless there is a special reason you need to.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: So far I had a minimum of 15 errors generated on whatever I tried, thought I'd spare you lot from it, suppose I might as well though, will edit in a moment.

Comment: Neil, basically I want to overload that operator from Rational so that it'd act in a different way when used from a method in the Matrix class

Comment: Also, (Neil) why not? I couldn't figure out yet how does a returned const ref/variable/object differ from a regular one, but the way it's implemented here is more or less the same as other familiar methods presented by my teacher.

Comment: Operator + shouldn't need to behave differently in different places as this will make your class very confusing. Instead consider adding a new function to Rational which does what you require.

Comment: Adding const to a value return type (not reference!) doesn't do anything much and just adds confusion. Usually the returned object is copied anyway, and if it isn't, if the caller of your function wants to call a non-const method on the returned object, that's their choice.

Comment: What about references then? Those are not copied and I still couldn't notice anything different with the returned value, I could change it as much as I wanted .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you asked for in the first part of your question indeed didn't seem to make sense like Barry stated, considering your edited info and comments though, is this perhaps what you were looking for?

```
bool trace(Rational& ans) const{return true;}
```

and then

```
template<typename T>
bool trace(T& ans) const{return false;}
```

If so, you were really close already, just that you need to place the template declaration on top and as the generic type instead of the other way around where you tended to the specific type :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot make `operator+(Rational, Rational)` do something different when called within the context of `Matrix<Rational>` than if it were called from some other source. That doesn't make much sense and seriously violates any concept of encapsulation.

If you want special logic within `Matrix` for

```
ans = ans + mat[i][i];
```

Then you can provide another layer of indirection so that `Matrix` internally can do the right thing for what it needs for `Rational`:

```
increment(ans, mat[i][i]);
```

Where:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
private: // <--
    template <typename U>
    void increment(U& lhs, const U& rhs) {
        lhs += rhs;
    }

    void increment(Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs) {
        // do something else
    }
};
```

Comment: Is the code I added under the "EDIT:" part what you meant?

Comment: @user3075303 Except it shouldn't be a template - just a normal function that takes a `Rational`.

Comment: Just for the sake of practice though, can I get it done like so? With an overloaded trace() function that takes a specific typename?

Comment: @user3075303 The way to take a specific type is to make it not an overload that is not a template.

Comment: bool trace(Rational& ans) const{return true;}
bool trace(T& ans) const{return false;}
I've got those two under the public section of the Matrix class and the code is refusing to compile, any idea why'd that be?

Comment: @user3075303 Probably because `T` is `Rational` and you're providing two equivalent overloads? Reread my answer and note the difference.

Comment: template<typename Rational>
 bool trace(Rational& ans) const{return true;}
 bool trace(T& ans) const{return false;}

Compiles but enters the T method even when the given value is of a Rational type? :/

Comment: @user3075303 Look man, I'm not going to debug your code for you based on two line snippets. If you have another question to ask, ask a new question and provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).